# How to toggle single element with this same class like another

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have HTML code something like this:

```
<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 1</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 1</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 2</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 3</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
```

If I click first img element I would like to toggle  "intro" class, but only the first element. If I click secont img, toggle second "intro", etc. How I can do this in jQuery? ("intro" has display:none; in CSS). I tried select pseudo-class:

```
$(".intro:first-child").click(function() {
    $("intro:first-child").toggle();
}
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe I should use id (id="intro-1", "intro-2", etc) instead class and select in jQuery each element separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** method and **[`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** pseudo class selector. Attach click event handler to the img tag and inside handler `this` refers to the clicked elements dom object.

```
// attach click event handler to all img tag
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    // get first `.intro` after the clicked img tag
    $(this).nextAll('.intro:first').toggle();
})
```

```js
$(".arrow").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.intro:first').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 1</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 1</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 2</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 3</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
```

Comment: It seems work. I will try this on my project and give you feedback.

Comment: @mrkkr91 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just by toggling class on the image itself. It will give you the possibility to style active image as well. Working example is shown below.

```js
$('img.arrow').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('image-active');
});
```

```css
.intro {
    display: none;
}

img.arrow {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

img.image-active {
    border-color: #0f0;
}

.image-active + h2 + .intro {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 1</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 1</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 2</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow"><h2 class="title">Heading 3</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
```

Comment: It seems work. I will try this on my project and give you feedback

Answer (score 1):

Combine `.nextAll()` and `.eq()`. Check below example

```js
$(function() {
  $("img.arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.intro').eq(0).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 1</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 1</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 2</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 2</p>

<img src="img.png" class="arrow">
<h2 class="title">Heading 3</h2>
<p class="intro">Lorem Ipsum 3</p>
```

Comment: It seems work. I will try this on my project and give you feedback

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.intro').toggle();
});
```